# Why oldversion of Django being used?

Tags: django

I have  created  a virtual environment with no-site-packages, activated the environment and installed django 1.4.3. But, when I do 'django-admin.py --version' it shows 1.3.  I am on Windows XP with Python 2.7. All my other projects use Django 1.3 and are not using virtual environment.

thanks

Comment: what does `python -c "import django; print django.VERSION"` give you? Just curious if this is a command line level issue or python path. If it gives you 1.4.3, you should just manually invoke django-admin.py that's within your env. Further commands always reference a specific file (like manage.py) so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hey John, if it does return 1.4.3, you should try my suggestion and manually invoke django-admin.py, as in `path-to-my-env/lib/python2.X/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject foo`. You will only need django-admin.py once. From then on, you can call `manage.py` directly which should use the right ENV